# Running a single test from gradle command line

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-project gradle setup

```
RootProject
     |
     ---- ProjectA
     |
     ---- ProjectB
```

`ProjectA` contains around 500 unit tests. Out of which 3 are failing in a single class `MyClass`.

Everytime I do:

```
./gradlew :ProjectA:test
```

it runs all 500 unit tests.

I am trying to run a single failing test inside `MyClass` or atleast only tests contained in `MyClass` to reduce the build time.

I tried:

```
./gradlew -D:MyProject:test.single=MyClass --no-rebuild :MyProject:test
```

However, it still continues to run all the tests.

Trying this works

```
./gradlew :MyProject:test --tests '*MyClass*'
```

but still takes lots of time as it seems to be parsing names of every test class to find the matching name.

Trying

```
./gradlew :MyProject:test --tests "com.mypackage1.mypackage2.MyClass.testMethod1"
```

throws the following error:

```
> No tests found for given includes: [**/*SomeTest.class](exclude rules) [com.mypackage1.mypackage2.MyClass.testMethod1](--tests filter)
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

This seems to be a simple use case which should be very obvious to do.

Edit 1:

`RootProject` build.gradle has:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'SomeProjToIgnore'}) {
test {
    forkEvery 1       

    //Exclude tests
    exclude '**/*SomeTest.class'
}
}
```

Edit 2:

```
./gradlew :MyProject:test --tests 'MyClass*'
```

is considerably faster. (notice removed '*' from the front). But still I don't know how to run a single test inside `MyClass`.

Comment: Where did that `**/*SomeTest.class` come from? Do you have some rules specified in the gradle file?

Comment: Yes. The RootProject build file has some tests to exclude inside configure subprojects block. That comes from there.